# Excel formulas: Dates A, B, C and D. How many days between A and B also fall between C and D

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Example:
A1 = 8/5/2004
B1 = 29/12/2004
C1 = 1/1/2003
D1 = 21/11/2004

I want to work out how many days between A and B also fall between C and D.  I can't get my head round what the formula to work this out would be. Can anyone please, help?

Comment: Can you figure it (for a specified set of values, like the ones you presented in the question) by hand? If so, watch yourself over your shoulder and see how you do it; then you're 57% of the way there. Hint: you might want to break the problem down into sub-problems for different cases. For example, in the case where B1 < C1, the answer is always 0.

Comment: You're referring just to the count of calendar days in common between the two sets of dates?  Assuming they are all stored as dates, you could do something like =(min(b1,d2)-max(a1,c1)).  If the dates are not guaranteed to be in that order, you would need to embed additional mins and maxes.

Comment: -1 http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-HP010070467.aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. At first find lower and upper bounds of intersection

   - The Lower bound of intersection (`IL`) is highest of `min([a;b])` and `min([c;d])`;
   - The Upper bound of intersection (`IU`) is lowest of `max([a;b])` and `max([c;d])`;
2. Then count days in range `[IL;IU]`, assuming that it's zero if `IL>IU`

   ```
   IL=max( min(a,b) , min(c,d) )
   IU=min( max(a,b) , max(c,d) )
   DAYSCOUNT= min( 0, IU-IL+1)`
   ```

After substitution we get

```
 min( 0, min(max(a,b), max(c,d)) - max(min(a,b), min(c,d)) + 1 )`
```

"+1" in the dayscount is needet or not depends on what do you mean under "between" or "within", include bounds or not. there are three cases obviously.

- `+1`- in the range (include the bounds)
- `+0`- from startdate to end date
- `-1`- between theese dates, but not inclusive